# How can I change the reference state in Modelica.Media.Water?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

Water media models given in Modelica.Media.Water are defined based on the reference at 273.15K and 1bar. As far as I can see there is no way of changing the reference state, for example, to 298.15K and 1bar. On the other hand this is possible for gas models; for gas media models we can set to excludeEnthalpyOfFormation=false and referenceChoice=Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Choices.ReferenceEnthalpy.ZeroAt25C. I had to edit the source code of Modelica.Media.Water to fix this issue and this is a messy solution, there are must be better solution. I think Modelica.Media.Water media models should also have the possibility of changing the reference state. Any thoughts?

Comment: The Modelica IBPSA Library contains a water model for which the nominal conditions can be set by the user: https://github.com/ibpsa/modelica-ibpsa/blob/master/IBPSA/Media/Specialized/Water/ConstantProperties_pT/package.mo

Comment: Not a solution, check the documentation of Modelica.Media.Water (IF97.pdf) you would see that how u, h, rho, etc. are calculated. There are 5 regions defined, for example for region 1, thermodynamic properties are calculated using appropriate partial derivatives of the specific Gibbs free energy g, here the reference state defined at T=273.15K. g should be changed to g* = g + h_0 - T*s_0 where h_0 and s_0 are reference specific enthalpy and entropy at some given reference temperature, for example T0 = 273.15 + 25. I think Modelica.Media.Water library should be updated with this correction

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to create an issue in the MSL github in order to discuss that:
https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/issues